# How to Set a White theme for windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, themes

I am a android developer and iam new to windows phone 8 development.

So i am designing a App But over there i got the Theme as Black

So i want to change it to white only for this app which does not effect user setting

i followed [this url](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402557%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

But over there i want to know where should i need to mention about theme,in Manifest  But i don't have any idea about theme in windows phone 8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [PhoneThemeManager](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2012/01/phonethememanager/), it works well.

Comment: Sorry sir to accept it as an answer it said i need to wait for 5 min so i am  late..